# "В силах тяжких". Откуда это выражение?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, история

Откуда взялось выражение "В силах тяжких"?
Употребляется в значении многократно превосходящей, подавляющей мощи, в основном военной, но может говориться и о мощи авторитетов. Выражение нередкое и интуитивно понятное, но откуда именно эта, словно бы нарочитая формулировка?

Примеры:

Артефакт, позволявший Дальним, если можно так выразиться, действовать в Хьерварде и его окрестностях «в силах тяжких». (Перумов, из интервью)

Какие такие арабы? Откуда они взялись в силах тяжких, чтобы взять Константинополь во всей силе и славе его? (из интернет-публикации)

В Сирию они, вероятнее всего, вторгнутся «в силах тяжких» в самые ближайшие дни. (Стрелков, о Турции и Сирии)

Они стояли на блокпостах, но как только противник приближался в силах тяжких козицынские казаки делали ноги. (Стрелков, о событиях на Донбассе)

Похоже, что боевики, получив новую порцию финансирования и оружия, вновь намерены атаковать "в силах тяжких". (из интернет-публикации)

И если всё же исхитриться попасть внутрь - в силах тяжких, оставив за собой выбитые двери и трупы, или тихо и скромно, незаметно от хозяев - то можно отыскать множество ценных и занятных вещи... (Плотников, "Воплощение")

Но при Владимире Путине политический юмор вернулся в жизнь россиян в силах тяжких. (из интернет-публикации)

Вечером 8 числа БДК с десантом уже разгружались на абхазских берегах, а из Севастополя шла помощь в силах тяжких во главе с крейсером «Москва». (Норин, "Маленькая победоносная")

Между тем как другие Князья воевали с Половцами, и Хан Кончак овладел городом Римовым, а Кза в силах тяжких сожег все около Путивля, - Игорь оставался в плену у Половцев. (Шевырёв, из лекции)

Но обращает на себя внимание, что японцы взяли гору через полчаса после того, как русские прекратили огонь - кто знает, если бы В.К. Витгефт вышел бы в море «в силах тяжких» и продолжал обстрел, не возвращаясь в Тахэ, возможно японцы и не захватили бы эту возвышенность. (из интернет-публикации)

«Дэйли ньюс» отметила, что прерафаэлиты в 1851 году «являются в силах тяжких и придерживаются своих догматов с убежденностью мучеников, но в то же время вызывают уважение страстной преданностью этим принципам». (из интернет-публикации)

Comment: Приведите хоть один пример, пожалуйста. Я такого выражения не знал до вашего вопроса, а когда сунулся в поисковики, то обнаружил, что авторы, это выраженение использующие, вкладывают весьма разный смысл, подчас - противоположный.

Comment: Многократно слышимое мной выражение. Примеры приводить не буду, ибо они неисчислимы - поиск в гугле выдаст искомое, причём именно в том смысле, о котором написал я, либо (реже) в близком (например в переносном шутливом значении "во всей красе", "всей компанией", "во всеоружии"). Употребления в ином значении не встречал - только после нарочных поисков в инете обнаружил единичные случаи, типа "мне тяжело", "я обессилел". Случаи явно либо нарочно (ради шутки) ошибочные, потому что игнорируют устоявшийся фразеологизм, внося собственную коннотацию сочетания слов "[мои] силы" и "[мне] тяжко".

Comment: Без примеров вопрос будет скорее всего закрыт. Довольно странная позиция: спрашивать о том, что знаете только вы. А посылать в гугл вообще считается неприличным. Хотя, признаться, последнее время этим начали заниматься и некоторые местные корифеи, но не надо брать с них пример.

Comment: Комменты не форматируются. Примеры желательно желательно в вопросе. Комменты вообще мало кто читает.

Comment: Забавно, что на https://studwork.org/qa/russkiy-yazyk/1136965-v-silah-tyajkih-otkuda-eto-vyrajenie-zakryt-sobstvenno-vopros-v-zagolovke этот мой вопрос УЖЕ перепечатан в первоначальном варианте, и УЖЕ есть один ответ. Цитирую: "На основе выражения ударить во все тяжкие колокола — звонить с исключительной силой. БМС, 579; ФСРЯ, 485; БТС, 122, 1360; Мокиенко 1986, 52; Мокиенко 1990, 82-83; ШЗФ 2001, 40; ДП, 255; Ф 2, 216." Ответ если и верный, то всё равно недостаточный, потому что не объясняет именно той устойчивой формулировки, о которой я спрашивал.

Comment: Вообще-то ваш вопрос не от этого ответа. Там разбирается, если вы заметили, совршенно другое выражение "пцститься во все тяжкие".

Comment: Там человек пытается таким образом ответить на мой вопрос - найдя похожее выражение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В Сирию они, вероятнее всего, вторгнутся «в силах тяжких» в самые
> ближайшие дни. (Стрелков, о Турции и Сирии)

Забавно. Я тоже обратил внимание, на то, что большинство поисковых ссылок ведут на сайты определенной направленности. Может, это у них шиболет такой? Чисто для своих?

Безотносительно к личности автора, я без контекста не могу понять, что он имел в виду. То ли усиленную группировку, то ли трудности самого процесса.

(++) ===

Нашел у Соловьева.

> Батый, взявши Козельск, пошел в землю Половецкую. Отсюда начал он
> посылать воевод своих на города русские: взят был город Переяславль
> копьем[82], жители избиты. В то же время послал и на Чернигов:
> обступили город в ***силе тяжкой***; князь Мстислав Глебович, услыхав о
> нападении иноплеменных, пришел на них со всем войском своим, но был
> побежден; множество воинов его побито, город взят и запален огнем.

В таком контексте, честно говоря, отпадает не только вопрос о значении, но и вопрос о происхождении, поскольку это не фразеологизм, а обычное сочетание, и существительное и прилагательное используется в одном из своих возможных значений.

Таким образом, единственное что еще может вызывать вопросы - так это якобы непривычно частота использования, если оно так. Но тут  я ничем помочь не могу.

Еще.

> В лето 1240 пришел Батый к Киеву в силе тяжкой со многим множеством
> силы своей и окружил город и обнес его частоколом, и был город в
> стеснении великом

Якобы из Радзивиловской летописи (посмотрю факсимиле - уточню).
Тогда получается, что выражение вообще очень древнее. Но это не отменяет того, что мы имеем дело не с фразеологизмом и даже не с крылатым выражением.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Ипатьевская летопись - "Приде Батъıи Къıевоу в силѣ тѧжьцѣ". Вопрос закрыт. )))

Comment: Только почему не фразеологизм - это устойчивое выражение, специфической формы, вне которой ключевое слово имеет совсем другое значение. Вполне фразеологизм.